# PowerShell: Splitting an Array into two columns

Tags: powershell

I have an array with the following values:

```
| Firstname | Lastname         | Username |
|-----------|------------------|----------|
| person1   | person1_lastname | p1       |
| person2   | person2_lastname | p2       |
| person3   | person3_lastname | p3       |
| person4   | person4_lastname | p4       |
```

This is the code that produces the above results:

```
$finalUsers = foreach($person in $excludedUsers) {
    if ($person.Username -notin $ausLunchJobs.AssigneeUser -and $person.Username -notin $ausLunchJobs.AssigneeUser2) {
        $person | Select-Object Firstname, Lastname, Username
    }
}
```

I want to split that array into two columns and pair the `Username` data together.

Ideal output:

```
| Username | Username2 |
|----------|-----------|
| p1       | p2        |
| p3       | p4        |
```

Any guidance on how I can achieve something like this?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 1 new object per *row* you want displayed in the table:

```
$userPairs = for($i = 0; $i -lt $finalUsers.Count; $i += 2){
  $finalUsers[$i] |Select-Object Username,@{ Name='Username2'; Expression={ $finalUsers[$i+1].username } }
}
```

Result:

```
PS ~> $userPairs |Format-Table 

Username Username2
-------- ---------
p1       p2
p3       p4
```